# I have created a svg map and in that map i want to show some data from api.My api returns like this : [[{"AG":2665}],[{"AR":397}],[{"AI":27}]]

Tags: reactjs, database, api, svg, axios

I fetch the api with axios in react js and in console is returning but when i try to access and show it it doesnt show any value and returns the map multiple times.How can i show them in map?Thanks

Part of my code

```
  {count.map((ca,index) => (
          <svg
            baseprofile="tiny"
            fill="#7c7c7c"
            height="700"
            stroke="#ffffff"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth="2"
            version="1.2"
            viewbox="0 0 1000 643"
            width="1000"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            className='kl'
           
          >
           
            <a  key={index}
              xlinkTitle={ca.AG}
            >
              <path
                d="M50.2 488.8l-0.2 0.2-3.6 10-1.5 12.1-1.6 1.5-1.3 2-0.9 2.2-0.6 2.7 11-10.9 9.1-17.9 0.7 2 0.1 1.3 2.1 5.3 1 1.4 2.3 1.2 3.7-1.7 1.6 0.6 1.1 7.4-5.7 6.1-14.2 9.4-11.3 13.3-7.1 3.7-7.6-3.4-10 0.4-10.1 2.4-5.3 3.2 2.9-7 1.7-3.2 0.7-2.7-3.9-4.9-2.3-4.4 0.8-3.9 5.4-3.4 13.3-6.5 1.1-0.2 1.8 0.6 1.3 0.2 1.3-0.2 4.8-1.5 1-2.1-0.2-3 0.1-3.5 1.6-9 0.7-2.5 3.2-7.3 12.3 10.2 0.7-0.2z"
                id="CHE159"
                name="Genève"
              ></path>
            </a>
```